Issue with displaying Vue.js components inside q-expansion-item
I'm working on a Vue.js project using the Quasar Framework and I'm facing an issue. I have a list of items (essentialLinks) that I'm displaying using EssentialLink components inside a q-expansion-item. The EssentialLink components have some CSS styles defined (in another file), but these styles are not being applied when the EssentialLink components are rendered inside the q-expansion-item. But, the styles work fine for the EssentialLink components that are rendered outside of the q-expansion-item, after a q-separator.
I don't think the approach I'm using is correct, is there an alternative approach I should be using??
(I know the comments in the code aren't correct, but it was just to better illustrate the issues in the code)
<template>
    <!-- ↓↓↓ Here the styling doesn't work ↓↓↓ -->
    <q-expansion-item
        EssentialLink v-for="link in essentialLinksSubMenuMain"
        :key="link.title" 
        v-bind="link" 
        :miniState="drawerMiniState"
    >

    <!-- ↓↓↓Here the styling works just fine ↓↓↓ -->         
    <q-separator/>

    <EssentialLink v-for="link in essentialLinksSubMenu"   
        :key="link.title" 
        v-bind="link" 
        :miniState="drawerMiniState" />

    </q-expansion-item>
</template>




Could you include the code for the styles and contents of the expansion?

From the snippet you provided, it seems like an improper nesting of EssentialLink within the q-expansion-item without closing tags.
The structure should look like this:
<template>
  <q-expansion-item>
    <template v-slot:header>
      <!-- Your header here -->
    </template>

    <!-- Content inside the expansion item -->
    <EssentialLink v-for="link in essentialLinksSubMenu"
                   :key="link.title" 
                   v-bind="link" 
                   :miniState="drawerMiniState" />

  </q-expansion-item>

  <q-separator/>

  <EssentialLink v-for="link in essentialLinksSubMenu"
                 :key="link.title" 
                 v-bind="link" 
                 :miniState="drawerMiniState" />
</template>

also note that if you are using scoped CSS, it might not be applied to child components deeply nested or in those in different component files. You might want to
remove the scoped attribute or use deep selectors (::v-deep or /deep/) in Vue.js to ensure that styles penetrate shadow DOM boundaries.
.q-expansion-item ::v-deep .essential-link-class {
    /* your styles */
}


you can read more about this here https://vue-loader.vuejs.org/guide/scoped-css.html#mixing-local-and-global-styles also
check    https://github.com/vuejs/vue-loader/issues/957 and Styles don't apply on CSS scoped component

Thanks for answering. However, the issue is that the nesting of EssentialLink within the q-expansion-item is not as I thought. essentialLinksSubMenuMain content should serve as the "label" within the . The structure should be something like this is:
`



<-- Content -->


`

I'm wondering if there's a more proper way to nest essentialLinksSubMenuMain within the q-expansion-item. I attempted to use a different syntax, but it ended up rendering the q-expansion-item with Quasar's predefined library styling, so didn't work. But like you said, probably the problem is on the scoped CSS.
